# Jetty WebAppContext not found when running as Windows service

Tags: windows-services, jetty

I am updating Jetty 6 to Jetty 8. Everything else went smoothly, but I have trouble getting my application to work when running Jetty as a Windows service. I'm using [Java Service Wrapper](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com) with WrapperJarApp integration method.

Seemingly everything works fine. There are no errors from Wrapper, Jetty or my application. I turned on Jetty debugging and there are no apparent warnings or errors. What Jetty is telling me when starting is:

```
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/11/21 10:50:54 | WrapperManager: Initializing...
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/11/21 10:50:55 | 2013-11-21 10:50:55.231:INFO:oejs.Server:jetty-8.1.14.v20131031
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/11/21 10:50:55 | 2013-11-21 10:50:55.239:INFO:oejdp.ScanningAppProvider:Deployment monitor C:\jetty-8.1.14\webapps at interval 1
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/11/21 10:50:55 | 2013-11-21 10:50:55.243:INFO:oejd.DeploymentManager:Deployable added: C:\jetty-8.1.14\webapps\MyApp
STATUS | wrapperm | 2013/11/21 10:50:58 | MyApp started.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/11/21 10:50:58 | 2013-11-21 10:50:58.715:INFO:MyApp:Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/11/21 10:51:02 | 2013-11-21 10:51:02.630:INFO:oejdp.ScanningAppProvider:Deployment monitor C:\jetty-8.1.14\contexts at interval 1
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/11/21 10:51:02 | 2013-11-21 10:51:02.658:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8080
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/11/21 10:51:02 | 2013-11-21 10:51:02.660:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8080
```

So apparently Jetty has found my app. However, if I go to `http://localhost:8080/`, it gives me 404 (as it should) and says "Contexts known to this server are:" without any known contexts. If I start Jetty without JSW using start.jar, it says:

```
Contexts known to this server are:

    /MyApp ---> o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{/MyApp,file:/C:/jetty-8.1.14/webapps/MyApp/},C:\jetty-8.1.14\webapps\MyApp
```

So obviously there is some problem with the context even though the app seems to be deployed normally. I first assumed this is some working directory problem but I have already tried replacing all Wrapper configuration paths with absolute paths as well as specifying the wrapper working directory. I also tried putting all the wrapper files in the Jetty root directory as instructed somewhere.
Any ideas what could be causing this problem when running as a service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I had too much stuff in my configuration file. I had diligently followed an example I found and added all kinds of JAR files etc to my classpath. Apparently there were too many and I believe Jetty was trying to load the same context more than once. Now I have only the following classpath and app parameter settings and everything is working fine:

```
wrapper.java.classpath.1=../lib/wrapper/wrapper.jar
wrapper.app.parameter.1=../start.jar
```